# What type of stuff should someone read to improve their email skills?

Tags: narrative, business-writing, email

I've heard that writers should read the type of stuff they want to write. Usually that implies really good fiction and prose, but I want to write great emails to my colleagues and network. What types of stuff should I read?

While various sites put out "how-to" guides almost daily, I'm interested in finding examples of good business writing in real life. There's a difference between "Eliminate this one word from your writing for success at work!" and an actual letter eloquently written from a employee to a manager, for example. Both can be helpful, but real samples are much harder to find.

Jeff Bezos' [shareholder reports](https://www.amazon.com/p/feature/z6o9g6sysxur57t) are good, but they're a little longer than a typical email. They're still a great example of using narrative in business, so the length difference may not be a big problem.

One of the biggest challenges in reading good business correspondence is that so much of it is private. Where can I find good business communication to read, in order to pick up habits that will make me better at writing email?

Comment: I have learned that one of the greatest email skills is to know when _not_ to send an email and who _not_ to include in "CC:" list.

Comment: There are a gazillion of how-to's on the internet and books about "business writing": have you checked some of those?

Comment: I've read a half-gazillion of them already. I was asking more about real-life examples. There's a difference between reading good books on writing and widely reading good books. Both are good, but I'm interested in the latter as it applies to email. I've clarified the question.

Answer (score 2):

Court cases and decisions written by the courts are very bussinesslike and logical. They lay out arguments and information while trying to be clear and concise.

There are some really interesting cases out there that are also useful for understanding the legal system in whatever location you are living.

And perhaps articles about writing great emails?? :D

Comment: Thanks, I never would have thought of that. I'd appreciate it if you could link to some examples of court decisions you find especially well-written. It doesn't have to be my jurisdiction. Also I'm not interested in the "how-to" or advice articles, and I've clarified my question to say so.

Comment: Sure! You can use Oyez to search for decisions. Here's the information about [Korematsu v US](https://www.oyez.org/cases/1940-1955/323us214). Then if you click on the 'view case' on the left, it will take you to [Justia](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/323/214/case.html) so you can read the decisions. 
Some of these cases even have audio, like [Gideon v Wainwright](https://www.oyez.org/cases/1962/155), so you could potentially listen in the car. 
Some good cases (besides those mentioned already) include Miranda v Arizona, Citizens United v FEC, Obergefell v Hodges.

Comment: I prefer Supreme Court cases because all nine justices are incredible communicators (with the exception of Thomas, perhaps) and writers. They are also easily available to read.